# WPF c#: Reading from a text file

Tags: c#, wpf, text-files

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

   namespace Lumiplex_Cinemas
   {
       public partial class Booking : UserControl, ISwitchable
       {
           string movieName;

            public Booking()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    movieName = "Descriptions/miss_peregrines_home_for_peculiar_children.txt";
                    descriptionTextBox.Text = ReadingDesciptions(movieName);
            }

            public string ReadingDesciptions(string movieName)
            {

                //Tried both of these, still the same error
                string description = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(movieName);
                string description = File.ReadAllText(movieName);

                return description;
            }
        }   
   }
```

I'm trying to display the contents of the text file into a text box, but keep getting an error saying:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Descriptions\miss_peregrines_home_for_peculiar_children.txt'."

Sorry if I've not included everything you might need, I'll edit the post if so.

Comment: I assume the file is actually there, right?

Comment: directory not found. Is your Descriptions folder in your exe folder?

Comment: Sounds a lot like "C:\Descriptions\" doesn't exists...

Comment: why not assign the full path to the variable.

Comment: Yh, I've put the text file into a folder called "Descriptions", and changed the copy to output directory to "Copy if newer".                                                      Also I'm going to be reading in a lot of text files, so I've tried doing it in a better way (also the files won't be staying in the same directory)

Comment: Set the Build Action of the *file* in the "Descriptions" folder to Content and the Copy to Output Directory property to Copy if newer and it should work. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Build Action of the **file** in the "Descriptions" folder to Content and the Copy to Output Directory property to Copy if newer and it should work:

[image]

There is no folder created in the output directory unless there are some files in it.

Comment: YES! thank you, I've been tweaking with it for hours and didn't even know you could do that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your path doesn't exist because your not escaping your \'s

you want to either use something like this

```
movieName = @"Descriptions\miss_peregrines_home_for_peculiar_children.txt";
```

using this way you don't need to escape your \

```
movieName = "Descriptions\\miss_peregrines_home_for_peculiar_children.txt";
```

but looking at the path, it doesn't exist unless that's in your application folder but even then you should be doing it a different way

```
var exPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
//exPath is the path of the exe \ dll that is being run which this is what it looks like from your code example
var filePath = Path.Combine(exPath,"Descriptions", "miss_peregrines_home_for_peculiar_children.txt" );
```

personally I like Path.Combine because you don't have to worry about escaping characters and it will build the path up for you so you can easily add and manipulate it

If your folder isn't in the executing assembly folder you should fully qualify the path and then you wont get the error

Comment: is that "System.IO.Path" or "System.Windows.Shapes.Path"? Because it doesn't like just Path.Combine (says it's an ambiguous reference).

Comment: System.IO.Path is what you need

Comment: sorry, I have it in a using statement at the top of the file, but you can qualify it there if you want too

Comment: "No overload for method 'Combine' takes 3 arguments", I assume it doesn't like the "," between descriptions and miss....... I took it out and combined the description and miss... but then it just outputted the file name to the text box XD

Comment: Can you edit your code and show the edit to what you tried to only get the file name and ill take a look and see where its going wrong